# How did the Witches of the Boiling Isle banish giraffes to the human world?

Tags: the-owl-house

In the Disney Channel original animation Owl House, it was stated that the witches of the boiling isle banished giraffes to the human world.

This is initially seen as being a throwaway line of dubious authenticity by a character who is prone to exaggeration, but is later shown to be canonically true within the context of the show.

We know that some things occasionally cross from one world to another, but nobody seems to know how or why this happens, and nobody within canon has been show to be able to exploit this phenomena until season 3 when a natural portal was found. As demonstrated by the fact that Belos wasn't able to find any way to travel to the human world other than Eda's portal.

How, then, were giraffes banished to the human world?

Comment: I do not think there is an answer yet

Comment: @Yu Zhang, that is actually an answer in itself. It's perfectly permissible too post an answer saying that something hasn't been addressed in canon.